# Config file doesn't connect with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using MAMP and the problem here is the config file that won't to connect with a database,

```
<?php

define("HOST","localhost");
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "root");
define("DB", "inserttest");

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
?>
```

...

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$fathername = $_POST['fathername'];
$grandfathername = $_POST['grandfathername'];
$familyname = $_POST['familyname'];


$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO subventions (firstname,fathername,grandfathername,familyname) VALUES ('$firstname','$fathername','$grandfathername','$familyname')");

if ($sql == true) {

echo '<b> تم الإرسال </b>';
} else {
    echo '<b> فشل الإتصال </b>';
}  

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

...............................................................

Comment: var_dump($con); then see what you got

Comment: It is advisable to use `or die("error");` after SQL connection. That would let you know if you are connected to the DB

Comment: @Thamizhan I think the problem in second page because I added        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die ("error");      but didn't ger error

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some functions to check weather the connection has established or not

you can do like this

```
<?php

   define("HOST","localhost");
   define("USER", "root");
   define("PASS", "root");
   define("DB", "inserttest");

   $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
   if(mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
      die("Some Error Occured While COnnection to database :".mysqli_connect_error());
   }
?>
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can check existing file path.
Try Again.

```
<?php
//include(foldername/filename);
include('config.php') or die('File path error');
```

Comment: In alll ways I get else      echo
  " else {
 echo '<b> فشل الإتصال </b>';
} "

Answer (score 0):

> try this
>
> ```
>  
> $servername = "localhost";
> $username = "root";
> $password = "root";
> $dbname = "inserttest";
>
> // Create connection 
> $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,
> $password, $dbname); 
> // Check connection 
> if ($conn->connect_error) {
>     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } ?>
> ```
>
> ```
> include('config.php');
>
>
> $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
> $fathername = $_POST['fathername'];
> $grandfathername = $_POST['grandfathername'];
> $familyname = $_POST['familyname'];
>
>
> $sql = "INSERT INTO subventions
> (firstname,fathername,grandfathername,familyname) VALUES
> ('$firstname','$fathername','$grandfathername','$familyname')";
>
>
> if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
>     echo "New record created successfully"; } else {
>     echo "Error: " . $sql . "
> " . $conn->error; }
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: The php version is 7.0.0 and I used this way to connect with mysql on other host and it's worked

Comment: Sir, I get error , do I have to add mysql port with defines ? Mysql port is 8889

Comment: port is a optional parameter of mysqli_connect  method.define("port", "8889"); mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB,port);